# Replicate nexus repository in my local server

Tags: maven

I work in an organisation and we use nexus repositories. I want a simple approach of how can I replicate few groups from nexus repository in to local server so that maven downloads the dependencies from local server and not from nexus.

Comment: What do you mean by `..in to local server..`? If you are using a repository manager they will downloaded from there and being copied into your local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use local server in the sense of base machine then you use `clean install` as a maven goal. The build code will be available under `.m2/repository` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Install Nexus locally, create Proxy Repository for each of the repo or group that you want to have locally. In Proxy Repository you'd need to set up URLs to the remote repos.

Now point Maven to this local Nexus (e.g. with `<mirrors>` in settings.xml). First time Maven downloads a dependency it will go to Local Nexus which would grab the dependency from the remote one. This file is going to be cached in Local Nexus and further downloads won't hit the Remote Nexus.

PS: don't know why you would do this.